# get error app:dexDebug after add a class model or add a setter in exist model

Tags: java, android, compiler-errors

I am developing a project it has some class model now I need to add some new model or change past models when I am adding new model or add setter in old model at the compile time I am taking app:dexDebug error please let me know how can I solve it 
regards

```
    :app:dexDebug
UNEXPECTED TOP-LEVEL EXCEPTION:
com.android.dex.DexIndexOverflowException: method ID not in [0, 0xffff]: 65536
    at com.android.dx.merge.DexMerger$6.updateIndex(DexMerger.java:502)
    at com.android.dx.merge.DexMerger$IdMerger.mergeSorted(DexMerger.java:283)
    at com.android.dx.merge.DexMerger.mergeMethodIds(DexMerger.java:491)
    at com.android.dx.merge.DexMerger.mergeDexes(DexMerger.java:168)
    at com.android.dx.merge.DexMerger.merge(DexMerger.java:189)
    at com.android.dx.command.dexer.Main.mergeLibraryDexBuffers(Main.java:454)
    at com.android.dx.command.dexer.Main.runMonoDex(Main.java:303)
    at com.android.dx.command.dexer.Main.run(Main.java:246)
    at com.android.dx.command.dexer.Main.main(Main.java:215)
    at com.android.dx.command.Main.main(Main.java:106)
Error:Execution failed for task ':app:dexDebug'.
> com.android.ide.common.process.ProcessException: org.gradle.process.internal.ExecException: Process 'command 'C:\Program Files\Java\jdk1.7.0_45\bin\java.exe'' finished with non-zero exit value 2
```

Comment: Show us your `build.gradle`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

finally i found the problem 
that is relate to  the 65K Reference Limit [her you can see more detail about that](https://developer.android.com/tools/building/multidex.html#about)

what I did was I change app.gradle

***multiDexEnabled

dexOptions***

```
android {
    compileSdkVersion 21
    buildToolsVersion "21.1.2"
    defaultConfig {
        applicationId "org.example.test"
        minSdkVersion 17
        targetSdkVersion 21
        versionCode 1
        versionName "1.0"

        **multiDexEnabled true**

    }

    ***dexOptions{
        preDexLibraries false
    }***

    buildTypes {
        release {
            minifyEnabled false
            proguardFiles getDefaultProguardFile('proguard-android.txt'), 'proguard-rules.pro'
        }
    }
    productFlavors {
    }
}
```